# try/except block and ctrl-d/EOFError

Tags: python, try-except, eoferror

I'm trying to learn Python.
I'm using Windows 10 on a desktop PC.

I initially went through University of Michigan's 'Python for Everyone' on the edx.org platform. For that I used the Atom editor and installed Python from [www.python.org](http://www.python.org)
Installed version of Python is 3.10.4.

I then uninstalled Python and Atom and installed Anaconda/Spyder. The reason for doing this was that I wanted to make use of the tools from JPL/NASA for calculating and visualizing orbits (as in orbital mechanics; search for 'AWP orbital' on Youtube, you'll see what I wanted to do). I tried initially to install the required libraries, but as I had read in a post on this site, attempting to do this in Windows 10 will probably not work, so the recommendation was to use Anaconda as it comes with literally  everything. So after switching to Anaconda, I was able to run the samples that that Youtuber provided in his github, but I didn't understand enough to do anything else with it.

So, having realized that I'm in way over my head, still need to do more basic stuff in Python. I'm 47 so this stuff doesn't come easy to me. No prior programming experience other than messing around with C a bit in uni 20+ years ago to do number crunching.

Sorry for rambling on... in any case, now I'm going through the Harvard CS50 Introduction to Programming with Python on edx.org and I uninstalled Anaconda and went back to Atom and installed Python from python.org like the first time around.

Finally I'm getting to the question. Before installing Anaconda, when I used cmd or the powershell, I could use the ctrl-d to get the EOFError in a try/except block of code, but now when I use either cmd or powershell, ctrl-d just displays ^D but doesn't actually execute the break that I have after my except statement. I tried changing it to ctrl-c and changing the except to KeyboardInterrupt, and that does execute the break, but it seems it doesn't work quite the same way. It would seem that having switched to Anaconda and then back to a basic install from python.org is what caused this ctrl-d to not work anymore, but I don't have a clue as to what I need to do to restore this functionality.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ctrl-D to generate an EOF is a Unixism - I wouldn't expect that to work on Windows at all, unless you're running some Unix-ish environment like WSL.  Ctrl-Z is Window's native EOF - but that's only going to do anything if something is actively reading from the terminal, to interrupt a running computation Ctrl-C/KeyboardInterrupt is the proper method.

Comment: Hmm interesting. I don't have WSL, just bog standard Windows 10.  BUT - your mentioning ctrl-z made me try that and sure enough it worked as I expected it to. Yes, what I'm doing at the moment is very simple programs that prompt for user input at the terminal, check for proper type/format, then do something with the data and print an answer. These ask for repeated input using a while True loop and use the EOFError exception to get out of the loop. Ctrl-c, though it did get out of the loop, printed the prompt text one extra time so it didn't look right. Weird that ctrl-d worked before though

Comment: @jasonharper do make your comment into an answer, so I can accept it